# How do I add a Regex to C++ Class?

Tags: c++, lexer

I have been working on a the first part of a lexer for a custom programming language and I am getting this error every time I try to run it:

```
lexer.cpp:8:17: error: expected identifier before string constant
   std::regex re("print[(]([0-9]+)[)];");
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lexer.cpp:8:17: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
lexer.cpp: In member function ‘std::__cxx11::string Lexer::lex(std::__cxx11::string)’:
lexer.cpp:12:31: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘std::__cxx11::regex Lexer::re(int)’
     std::regex_search(s, m, re);
                               ^
lexer.cpp:8:14: note: declared here
   std::regex re("print[(]([0-9]+)[)];");
              ^~
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>


class Lexer {
  public:
  std::regex re("print[(]([0-9]+)[)];");
  std::smatch m;

  std:: string lex(std::string s) {
    std::regex_search(s, m, re);
    return m[1];
  }
};
int main()
{
    // Target sequence
    std::string s;
    Lexer lexer;

    while(true){
      std::cin >> s;
      std::cout << lexer.lex(s);
    // for each loop

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that this is not a full lexer, or even close, but I would be really thankful if you would help. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `()` to initialize a class member within the body of the class, but `{}` should work.  (e.g. `std::regex re{"print[(]([0-9]+)[)];"};`)  Check out [default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

Comment: Thanks @0x5453 !  It worked!